# JTextArea get user typed text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I use a `JTextArea` in which I use `setText` method to have some text while opening GUI.

Once text area is opened with the text I set, I typed some text, my intention is to get whatever text user types.

```
dataField = new JTextArea();
dataField.setText("sample#");
..
...
```

If I type "hello world"

sample#hello world

in text area and press enter I need to get only hello world in a string and not sample#hello world. I have tried with key listeners and 
appended the input characters to a string builder but backspace also creates a unreadable character an appends
to it.

Simply put, I need to get user typed text from text area.

Comment: The code you have posted is **NOT** enough to help!

Comment: You may be looking for _Text Prompt_, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5045770/230513).

Comment: Is `sample#` always the same? Just take the substring starting after `sample#` of datafield.getText()

Comment: @leigero No its not always the same

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement either. Since you are using a JTextArea it implies that you can have multiple lines. Does this mean that the start of each line has a token? Do you only want the text from the last token or all tokens?

Comment: @camickr The text area contains multiple lines but i am expecting the text from last token.. sample# is the last line in text area , so what ever i type after the last token i need to get that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sample# is the last line in text area , so what ever i type after the last token i need to get that text.

Read the `JTextArea` API:

1. `getLineCount()` so you know the number of lines
2. `getLineStartOffset()` and `getLineEndOffset()` to know the offsets of the text you need to get from text area. Add 7 to the start since you don't want to get the "sampler#" text.
3. `getText()`  to get the text using the offsets from above.

Answer (score 0):

String a="sample#"+datafield.getText();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String old = "sample#";
String s = dataField.getText().subString(old.length());
```

Good luck